# JQuery: Not targeting element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery I want to target an element which has the same `class` as the `body`. This is what I have so far:

```
var bodyClass = $('body').attr("class");

if($('#productnav .container ul li').hasClass(bodyClass)) {
alert(bodyClass);

var thetab = $('#productnav .container ul' + bodyClass);
    $(thetab).addClass("active");
}
```

The alert gets fired so there is clearly  a `li` that has the same class. The problem is that I cannot seem to target that specific `li`.

**The HTML**

```
    <div id="productnav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="accelerators" data-slide="0"><a class="active" href="/product-types/accelerators">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Accelerators</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="redispersible-powder-polymers" data-slide="1"><a href="/product-types/redispersible-powder-polymers">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Redispersible Powder Polymers</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="superplasticisers" data-slide="2"><a href="/product-types/superplasticisers">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Super- plasticisers</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="lightweight-fillers" data-slide="3"><a href="/product-types/lightweight-fillers">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Lightwight Fillers</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="cellulose-ethers" data-slide="4"><a href="/product-types/cellulose-ethers">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Cellulose Ethers</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="fibres" data-slide="5"><a href="/product-types/fibres">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Fibres</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="retarders" data-slide="6"><a href="/product-types/retarders">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Retarders</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="power-air-entrainers" data-slide="7"><a href="/product-types/power-air-entrainers">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Power Air Entrainers</span>
            </a></li>
            <li class="poraver-x" data-slide="8"><a href="/product-types/poraver-x">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;">Poraver X</span>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly comes up in the alert?

Comment: can you provide the html for this question?

Comment: could you tries to change $('#productnav .container ul' + bodyClass); to $('#productnav .container ul li.' + bodyClass);

Comment: `hasClass` will accept only one class... I believe, the number of classes in the body might be more...

Comment: if you can add the body tag to check the class it would be great

Comment: @PraveenKumar the alert shows the current class of the body element

Comment: Man, I know that. I am asking what's the content. Be specific dude. @KyleD...

Comment: @PraveenKumar the body class is different for each page. Showing the body class would be pointless.

Comment: Okay, does it contain a space character?

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for the help but it seems I missed a `.` when I was targeting the element

Comment: @KyleD Glad it solved. I thought that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `.`

```
var thetab = $('#productnav .container ul .' + bodyClass);
//----------------------------------------^
$(thetab).addClass("active");
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I knew there was something I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: @KyleD  do a `bodyClass.split(' ').join('.')` in case `<body>` has many classes